# Check value of two different length columns in different dataframes python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a question regarding comparing two columns of different lengths from different data frames.
I have two data sets that are between the same dates but just separated by time measurements. For example one Dataframe `df_daily` has a column `Date` where the date is a str ('`2/1/2022`') as an example. The other one is `df_minute` where it has data on minutes but also has a column named `Date` with the same properties.

I have tried to check with a nested for loop however the data frames are larger and it takes for ever to compile the output.

The length for `df_minute` is 145966 and `df_daily` is 157.

Below is how the nested for loops look. The goal for this is to append the value from the `df_daily` to the index location where the dates are the same in `df_minute`. I want to append the value at column `Sales`.

```
salesList=[]
for i in range(len(df_minute)):
dateMinute = df_minute.iloc[i]["Date"]

for j in range(len(df_daily)):
    dateDaily = df_daily.iloc[j]['Date']
if dateMinute == dateDaily:
    salesList.append(df_daily.iloc[i]['Sales'])

df_minute['Daily Sales'] = salesList
```

Is there a faster and more efficient way of doing this. I think this can be done with V look up in excel but is there a way to this better with python?

Let me know if there is anything I can do to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any data, but vlookup in pandas should be something like this:

```
df_minute.merge(df_daily, on='Date')
```

If df_daily has more columns you don't need to merge everything:

```
df_minute.merge(df_daily[['Date', 'Sales']], on='Date')
```